# Nodejs Express not loading script files

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to run a angular app thru node-express.

**1** File Structure

```
AngularNode
    public
        /core.js
        /index.html
    project.json
    server.js
```

**2** server.js

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8000);
console.log("App listening on port 8000");
```

**3** index.html

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>    
     <script src="./core.js"></script>
........
```

**4** core.js

```
angular.module('MySystem',[])
.controller('AppController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.Name ="Testing Text";
}]);
```

When I tried to run this app using `node server.js` this, `index.html` file is getting loaded properly, however this is not detecting or loading `core.js` file. and I am getting following errors

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <           core.js:1
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=MySystem&p1=Error%3…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)   angular.js:38
```

Now, when I open `index.html` file directly from explorer, this is working **OR** when same code I move from core.js to inline html, under `<head>` with `<script>` block it is working.

I am not sure, why `core.js` not detecting or loading when I run thru node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the Solution with few modifications:

**1** Added line in `server.js`
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` after line 
`var app = express();`

**2** Case correction(Capital 'f') for function from `res.sendfile('./public/index.html');` to `res.sendFile('./public/index.html');`

Now I can see `core.js` is detected and working fine.

Comment: One more observation and fix:


With the above code for `res.sendFile('./public/index.html');`, **node console**  _throws error_ 

`TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile` 

to fix this modify as per `('./public/index.html',{"root": __dirname});`

Answer (score 1):

The `app.get('*', function(req, res) {`  is a catch all rule for all `get` request and will also match the `./core.js` request. So for the `./core.js` your express app will also send the html file.

You should use [express.static](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) instead:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'));
```